# using focus() and onload() with CakePHP

Tags: javascript, cakephp-1.3

Is there a way by which we can set the focus to a particular textbox in CakePHP. Something like the textbox we have on the home page of google.We load the page and start typing.Is it possible to achieve the same in Cake.

does cake support javascript's onload function.I only need it for my view and dont want to include an external file for this.I have a user defined function that works fine but the onload doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use javascript between your head tags as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
        document.getElementsByName('txt1')[0].focus(); // txt1 is the name of textbox
    } ​ 
</script>
```

**Update:** If you want to use it only for a particular page then you can keep it in that view and in that case you can simply paste it right after the `HTML` code as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementsByName('txt1')[0].focus(); // txt1 is the name of textbox
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Heera.Your logic worked.I had been banging my head because of this problem.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript on any webpage or application, so using CakePHP is not a restriction. One of the differences on Cake from other technologies is that you have a layout which is loaded always with your view and you usually import all your scripts there (you can import the scripts on the view too).

So then, you can use onload function for your page on Cake without any problem. In this case, you may want to add that function in your view within `<script>` tags

Comment: Thank you pollirrata for you help